# When using SDL_RendererCopy() on out of boundaries textures, am I wasting in computing power?

Tags: c++, rendering, sdl

When using `SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, srcRect, destRect)` if I provide a destRect that is out of the window's boundaries (lets say the window is 100px by 100px and the texture's destRect is (500, 500, 10, 10) (that is xPos, yPos, width, height), am I wasting in performance by calling that function and making it do extra work for something that will never be shown in the screen or does that function already know about this and discards the operation automatically?

Comment: Even if it *"discards the operation automatically"*, doing so will require a tiny bit of CPU time. The question is how much time it takes. Measure it!

Comment: Ok. I'll see whats the difference in time between rendering ~500 textures inside the windows boundaries vs outside.
Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Not sure if I did this right (Ill paste the code for anyone interested in checking), but it seems like SDL does not waste a lot of time when you tell it to render out of boundaries textures.
It takes SDL 135ms to render a bunch of textures within the boundaries but only 9ms to render the same amount outside.

Comment: nvm about the code it don't have enough space here.